# How to Run Fan Only with Thermostar Furnace With G Wire

Tags: wiring, thermostat, furnace, fans

I have a Thermostar Furnace that works great for Heating our home.  We do not have AC and do not want that.  But, we do want to be able to just run the fan without heat.  The W and RH wires were connected and I thought I could just connect the G wire and it would work.  But, that doesn't seem to be the case.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace, and/or pictures of the thermostat wiring at both ends?